# Read GnuPG encrypted emails transperently on iOS

Tags: ios, email, encryption

Are there any tools that integrate OpenPGP/GnuPG with the mail reader on iOS

I've heard that [iPGMail](https://ipgmail.com/) and [oPenGP](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/opengp/id414003727?mt=8), probably [SecuMail](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/secumail/id414328661?mt=8) too, all require that you copy & paste an encrypted email into the application, which sounds obnoxious.  Any of these tools managed to actually integrate with iOS's mail reader the way GPGTools does on OS X yet?

Yes, I'm aware Apple's Mail readers support S/MIME, but that's less secure in practice.

Comment: Why do you say S/MIME is less secure in practice?

Answer (score 3):

Do you need to use Copy & Paste with PGP/GPG mail?

No, that is not required.  For iPGMail:

- Click the encrypted attachment to open it - you see the encrypted
  text.
- Click on the transfer button (at top right).
- Open in iPGMail.
- Enter your pgp password and see the unencrypted message.

Do any of the tools integrate like GPGTools on OS X?

This is impossible given Apple's sandboxing requirements.  As an aside this may well be a good thing as it avoids the annual scramble by GPG developers when Apple updates OS X and its Mail app.